# Cannot resolve symbol 'NameValuePair'

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Знаю, что в gradle.build нужно внести запись, но у меня в проекте нет такого файла, т.к пишу не под андроид. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как исправить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: возможно надо подключить 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpcore', version: '4.4.6'

Comment: @Russtam, что-то я не врубаюсь как подключить..

Comment: если проект без системы сборки, то в свойства проекта (Project Structure) в раздел Libraries добавить нужную библиотеку (заранее скачанную на пк), тогда она появится в структуре проекта в разделе External Libraries (в нижней части вышеприведенного скрина), и соответственно, ее классы будут доступны для использования в проекте